# XSLT - Remove specific value from attribute but keep other values

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

**I have following XML input:**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">td text</td>
            <td style="color: red; width: 25px; text-align: center; margin-left: 10px;">
                <span>span text</span>
            </td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please note that I have other nodes in the same document that should not be touched.

I want to remove certain attribute values from an element (in this case from td).
Let's say I want to remove the width value within a style attribute.
I don't know where in the style-attribute the width-value is set, it could be anywhere.
The span in the td doesn't really matter (this and some other elements are there in the input).

**I expect the output to be like this:**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="margin-left: 10px;">td text</td>
            <td style="color: red; text-align: center; margin-left: 10px;">
                <span>span text</span>
            </td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I prefer using XSLT1, I did not bring the replace() function to work yet (but maybe I am doing something wrong).

**I tried using this XSLT:**

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="td/@style">
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(., 'width:.[[:digit:]]+px;', '')" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" /> 
</xsl:template>
```

I am still a beginner in XSLT and this above doesn't work and I did not find a solution here.
Also, I don't know the width-value so I would need to replace the value with a regex (I used "width:.[[:digit:]]+px;") or something.
Is there maybe a easier method that can replace every specific value? So I could remove text-align aswell without having to think of a new regex?

I really hope that you can help me with this (surely easy) problem.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `replace` is XSLT/XPath 2.0 so I am not sure why you say "I prefer using XSLT1". As for a general solution, I think you would need to implement a CSS parser or maybe transformation first to handle a CSS style attribute value. So I don't think it is an easily solved problem, for instance a CSS `width` value is not restricted to the `px` unit.

Comment: "*this above doesn't work*" That's a useless description. You should report the exact result and reproduce verbatim any error messages received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Let's say I want to remove the width value within a style attribute. I
>   don't know where in the style-attribute the width-value is set, it
>   could be anywhere.

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="td/@style[contains(., 'width:')]">
    <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., 'width:')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(., 'width:'), ';')" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Note**:

> I want to remove certain attribute values from an element (in this
>   case from td).

Actually, what you want is to remove certain *properties* from the `style` *attribute*. The above will work for removing a **single** property; if you want to remove more than one, you'll have to use a recursive template to do it.

---

### Added:

> Will there be an issue if the style contains `border-width:1px` as
>   this become `border-`?

Yes, this could be a problem. A possible solution would be:

```
<xsl:template match="td/@style">
    <xsl:variable name="style" select="concat(' ', .)" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($style, ' width:')">
            <xsl:attribute name="style">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($style, ' width:')" />
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after($style, ' width:'), ';')" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

However, this assumes that the `;` separator in the source document is always followed by a space (as it is in the given example). Otherwise it gets more complicated.

Comment: If `width` comes last in a `style` attribute, it does not have to be terminated by a semicolon.

Comment: Will there be an issue if the style contains `border-width:1px` as this become `border-`?

Comment: @TimC Yes, that *would* be a problem. I have added a possible solution to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using XSLT 2.0 (as `replace` is not supported in 1.0) you can use `\d` to match a digit in regular expressions, so you can write your pattern like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '( | $)width:\s*\d*px;?', '')" />
```

Note the `\s*` is used to match zero or more characters of whitespace, so allow for `width:10px` or `width: 10px`. Also not `( | $)` is used to ensure a space before `width` (or if it is at the start), so that properties like `border-width` are not matched.

If you wanted to handle units other than `px` you could do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '( | $)width:[^;]+;?', '')" />
```

Read up on regular expressions at http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/04/tr.html.

Comment: Thank you, but I think somehow my processor doesn't work with the replace() function as I get an error while checking "funcall(replace, [step("self", -1), literal-expr(width:\s*\d*px;), literal-expr()])".'"
This is my declaration: <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

Is my processor causing this issue? If so, I think I'd need a XSLT1.0 template :-(

Comment: It sounds like you are using XSLT 1.0. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr to find out what version you are using (The answer applies anywhere, not just in solr).